# Using js helper function from parent and child component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a parent component (say, `CustomerOrder`) and a child component (say `OrderLine`). In `CustomerOrder.vue`, I will be including multiple `OrderLine`  by iterating over an array. I have a helper js function that I need to use in both `CustomerOrder` and `OrderLine`. I can import this js file in `CustomerOrder` and call the js function. But I cannot import the js file in `OrderLine` because it gives an error (`vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: _vm.formatNumber is not a function`) when the function is being called. My requirement is to use the helper js function from parent and multiple children of the same type.

**CustomerOrder.vue**:

```
<template>
    <span class="caption">{{ formatNumber(1500) }} LKR</span>
    <v-layout wrap>
      <order-line v-for="line in orderLines" :key="line.id" :general_data="line"></order-line>
    </v-layout>
</template>

<script>
    import { formatNumber } from '../utils'
</script>
```

**OrderLine.vue**:

```
<template>
    <span class="caption">{{ formatNumber(2300) }} LKR</span>
</template>

<script>
    import { formatNumber } from '../utils'
</script>
```

`vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:1888 TypeError: _vm.formatNumber is not a function` is raised when `formatNumber` in OrderLine is called. Is it because

FYI:

**utils.js**:

```
import Numbro from 'numbro'

export function formatNumber (value, numberOfDecimals) {
  return Numbro(value).format({
    thousandSeparated: true,
    trimMantissa: true,
    mantissa: numberOfDecimals
  })
}
```

Comment: Could you include the code where you use the imported `formatNumber`? Just importing it isn't enough to make it available in your template, it would need to be included somewhere within the `<script>` section, e.g. in `methods`.

Comment: I use `import { formatNumber } from '../utils'` to import the js in both the components as I have shown above and am using it as `formatNumber(1500)` and `formatNumber(2300)` as shown above as well

Comment: `CustomerOrder.vue` and `OrderLine.vue` are located in the same directory, correct?

Comment: Yes they are...

Answer (score 2):

You should add (define) `formatNumber` in `methods` like

```
methods: {
  formatNumber
}
```

otherwise you can't use it in template

Also you can check https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/filters.html and add `formatNumber` to `filters` instead of `methods`. Then use in template like
`{{ 2300 | formatNumber }}`

Comment: I am new to Vue and am learning. Could you please advise me as to how to use a helper function across the application without duplicating the code?

Comment: If you want to use this `filter` across the application, then you should add it to `filters` where you define your Vue app - `new Vue(...`

Comment: he doesn't have to add it in his methods .... i've used many functions by just importing ... i think the issue is somewhere else

Comment: I just followed your link and it seems I can use filters... anyway if there are a lot of filters like this, can I move them to a separate file? just asking this since I think I'll run into it in the near future... :)

Comment: Sure, you can create filters file where exporting multiple filters and then import all at once and set to `filters`

Comment: @Dadboz I thought the same... since I have little knowledge in Vue, thought of posting it here. Emils suggested using filters... I will be giving it a try. But I prefer if I can use the approach I took if it is the right way (if the issue is somewhere else)